# Custom Notification not working on some devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

Im using Parse as my backend and currently have set up notifications via their SDK. Following is the code

```
@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    //TODO: Change ringtone
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
        message=jsonObject.getString("message");
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setContentTitle(jsonObject.getString("heading"));
        builder.setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.launcher_icon_plus);
        builder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + context.getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.my_sound));
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        resultIntent = new Intent(context, DispatchActivity.class);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        int mNotificationId = 123;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, builder.build());
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I send the JSON as {"heading":"....", "message":"...."} and it is working fine. I have placed a custom ringtone in my raw folder called my_sound. The issue I am facing is, this notification is not working on some phones. More specifically, it is working perfectly (including custom sound for notification) on several phones by LG, Samsung and Xiaomi which are running on either 4.4 or 5.1. But [on phones such as this](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/micromax-canvas-spark/634407752835) the notification does not appear at all or in some cases just the alert is shown without any sound. These models by Micromax do have android 4.4 and above so its not an issue regarding the android OS.

If the notification appears, its never accompanied by sound (the custom or default). Sometime it doesnt appear at all. Could someone please guide me/ give me some advice on how to tackle this problem. I will try to arrange for a phone so I can debug it .  bump!

Comment: Did you find any solution, actually i am also stuck at custom sound which does not work in some devices such as redmi note 5 pro.

Comment: @AnuragKumar No I did not. Came to the conclusion that the behavior is different due to subtle differences between manufacturers in their Android OS. For example phones by Xiaomi do not recognize certain android functions (don't remember the names), so you will need to add checks within the code. No idea how to though. I am using Redmi Note 3 and noticed that some custom sounds like the ones by Ola do not work on my phone but they do on my Samsung

Comment: As far as my problem is concerned it was Oreo version and i was not sending notification channel id from my server. Anyways, thanks for replying back.